# Gem Cells works bad with Simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, cells

I've set up Cells ([link to github](https://github.com/apotonick/cells)) self contained cell. Nothing special. And everything works except one thing.

When a view template inside the cell has a `simple_form_for` helper - it doesn't work.
Says

```
undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<SubscribeForm::Cell:0x0000000a0ceba8>
```

Don't understand why. Any ideas? Other helpers (`link_to`, etc) work fine. And `simple_form_for` does work on other pages where there are no cells. Oh, and it's not about "restarting the server". Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I've never played with cells but have you tried to require simple_form on your SubscribeForm cell file?

Comment: Yep, tried to require SimpleForm, ActionSupport, ApplicationHelper etc. Nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved by doing

```
load('action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb')
include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper
include SimpleForm::ActionViewExtensions::FormHelper
```

Comment: I had to also `include ActionView::RecordIdentifier`, see https://github.com/apotonick/cells/issues/260